# SCSS compiler replacing " with ÔÇť

Tags: css, sass, sublimetext3

I'm using sublime text 3 and SCSS compiler downloaded through package control. After having:

```
&:before{
content: "“";
}
```

it replaces mine content to:

```
content: "ÔÇť";
```

Is there any way to have good content? I have tagged my question under sass because I wasn't able to find SASS tag :)

Comment: Make sure that source file is in the same encoding that SASS expects.  Most likely SASS is expecting UTF-8 and the file was saved in UTF-16 (or verse-visa).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the compiler is having issues with the special character. Instead of using the special character directly, try using the unicode value.

```css
#test:before {
  content: "\201C"
}
#test:after {
  content: "\201D"
}
```

```html
<span id="test">span</span>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks, one more question, where did you get this codes for characters :)?